# Placeholder controls count always return 0 in button click

Tags: c#, asp.net, placeholder

I created some TextBox dynamically using the code below and I entered some text in this TextBox. Now I want to read this control's ID while adding the text into a database. How can I get the ID of this TextBox on the click of a Button.

```
for (int i = 0; i < dv_count; i++)
{
    TextBox txt_box = new TextBox();
    txt_box.Text = "";
    txt_box.ID = "s" + i;
    placeholder1.Controls.Add(txt_box);
}

protected void btn_act_proceed_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int count = placeholder1.Controls.Count; //always return 0

    if (count > 0)
    {
        int dv_count = count / 2;

        for (int i = 0; i < dv_count; i++)
        {
            TextBox  lbl_type = (TextBox )placeholder1.FindControl("s" + i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your text box is lost when you loop through to the next i

Comment: In your updated edit.. whats placeholder1?

Comment: its creating. Please see my updated post.

Comment: In which event you are adding those text boxes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

In your **Aspx** Page

```
<div runat="server" id="plcholder">
</div>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="Button1_Click" />
```

now in **code behind**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    populate();
}

public void populate()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        TextBox tb = new TextBox();
        tb.ID = "s" + i;
        tb.Text = "Hello" + i;
        plcholder.Controls.Add(tb);
    }
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int cont = plcholder.Controls.Count;

    for (int i = 0; i < cont-1; i++)
    {
        TextBox tx = (TextBox)plcholder.FindControl("s" + i);
        Response.Write(tx.Text);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Control will be lost during `postback`. So on `preinit` you need to create the controls again.
Or you can keep your controls in session and get it back from postback.  
A good link http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3684/Retaining-State-for-Dynamically-Created-Controls-i
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/502251/How-to-create-controls-dynamically-in-ASP-NET-and

Answer (score 0):

I don't see you adding controls to the placeholder in first place.  try this

```
for (int i = 0; i < dv_count; i++)
{
    TextBox txt_box = new TextBox();
    txt_box.Text = "";
    txt_box.ID = "s" + i;
    placeholder1.Controls.Add(txt_box);
}

TextBox lbl_type = (TextBox)placeholder1.FindControl("s" + i);
```

Comment: when are you running this loop ?